# dx scheduler - Prevent modal Opening on click (angular)

Tags: angular, devexpress

I am experiencing a specific problem in the dev express dx scheduler plugin.
I need to add a new schedule when I click on the calendar, but there is a native plugin modal that is not letting me use the modal service that I have already implemented. I looked in the documentation and found the following "solution":

HTML:

```
<dx-scheduler (onAppointmentFormOpening)="cancel($event)" > </dx-scheduler>
```

TS:

```
cancel(e: any) {
e.cancel = true;
}
```

But I realized that when calling this cancel, I lose access to all other events (which makes it impossible for me to use this flow to call my default modal). I would like to know if anyone has had this problem and if so, how did you solve it?